# CSS media only screen issue

Tags: html, css

There are a few images in our code. The code I have pasted below is which we used to solve the compatibility issue in tablet. But the image looks massive on a tablet. On a mobile phone, image looks fine.

CSS:

```css
/* #Tablet (Portrait) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 571px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    /* COMMON */
    .mobile {height: 35px; display: block;}
    #hide_20px {display: block;}

    /* DIV */
    #wrap {max-width:100%;}

    /* BUTTONS */
    .button_img {width: auto; height: auto;}

    /* HEADER */
    #pex_logo{max-width: 100%; margin-left: 30px;}


    /* NAV */
    nav {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-image: none; background: #F2F2F2; height: auto; border-radius: 0px; width: 100%; border: none;}
    nav ul {width: 100%; display: none; height: auto;}
    nav li {padding: 0px; width: 33%; float: left; position: relative;}
    nav li a {color: #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; border-right: 1px solid #666}
    nav li:first-child a{margin-left: 0px;}
    nav a {color: #FFF; padding: 0px; text-align: left; width: 100%; text-indent: 20px; line-height: 30px; background: none;}
    nav li:last-child a {border-right: 1px solid #666;}
    nav a:hover {color: #FFF; background: #999;}
    nav li:last-child a:hover  {color: #FFF; background: #999;}
    nav .current a {font-weight: bold; color: #000; background: none;}
    #gap {display:block; width:20px; float: left}
    .slide-trigger { display: block;  }
    .navigation { display: none; }

    /* PEX CONTENT LEFT */
    #pex_content_left {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; float: none;}

    /* PEX CONTENT RIGHT */
    #pex_content_right_down {display:none;}
    #pex_content_right { max-width: 100%; width: 100%; float: none;}
    #pex_content_right aside {width: 100%; float: right; border-right: 1px dotted #999; border-bottom: 1px dotted #999; padding-bottom: 0px; padding: 5px;}

    /* PEX FOOTER */
    footer {max-width: 96%;}
    footer p {line-height:normal; padding: 5px; padding-left: 0px;}
    footer ul {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; float: left;}
    footer ul li {}
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!--Mobile-->

<div id="pex_content_right_down" class="clearfix">
    <!-- START 'pex_content_right' -->
    <aside>
        <div id="pex_content_right_header">Text</div>
        <div id="pex_content_right_content">
            <center>
                <img src="ipad-img.jpg" alt=""  border="0"/>
            </center>
            <br>

            <img src="reg-button.png" border="0"></a>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <div id="pex_content_right_header">Refer</div>
        <div id="pex_content_right_content">
            <center>
                <img src="laptop-speaker.jpg" alt=""  border="0"/>
            </center>
            <br>

            <img src="green-button.png" border="0"></a>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <div id="pex_content_right_header">Details</div>
        <div id="pex_content_right_content"> 


        </div>
    </aside>
</div>

<!--Mobile End -->
```

Comment: Are u using any viewport meta tag ?

Comment: You never end your first comment, so the parser doesn't see the media query.

Comment: @Neha : I have not used any viewport meta tag

Comment: @Mr Lister : Comment is not a problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK, without a viewport meta, how many dots to the logical pixel?

Comment: just suggestion use this meta tag . maybe tablet is zooming the image - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: @Neha : Doesn't work. How to specify the device-width in that ?

Comment: that the default device width and if we specify it will apply to all device same. To understand u can add like this <meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: can u share the link of this page so we can debug it..??

Comment: Also, it might help to tell us which tablet(s) and which mobile phone(s) you're testing on.